# Could someone break down this grouping problem for me?

Tags: algorithms, group-theory

I am trying to work through this programming problem but I can't progress because I genuinely don't understand what it is that its asking me.

> New Students are arriving at college. Initially the students don't know each other, and each has a circle of friends limited to themselves. As the semester progresses, groups of friends form.
>
> As they arrive, each students gets an ID number, 1 to n.
> You will be given three arrays, each aligned by index. The first array will contain a `queryType` which will be either `Friend` or `Total`. The next two arrays, `students1` and `students2`, will each contain a Student ID.
>
> If the query type is `Friends` the two students become friends.
> If the query type is `Total`, you must report the sum of the sizes of the groups of friends for the two students.
> For example, if you have `n=4`students numbered 1-4 and you receive the following queries:
>
> ```
> Friend 1 2   Friend 2 3   Total  1 4
> ```
>
> Students will start as discrete group {1}, {2}, {3} and {4}. Students 1 and 2 become friends as do 2 and 3. The new groups are {1,2}, {2,3} and {4} which simplifies to {1,2,3} and {4}. We then total the number of friends for student 1 = 3 and student 4 = 1 for a total =4. Notice that student 3 is part of student1's circle of friends indirectly through student 2.
>
> Functional Description
> Complete the function `getTheGroups` in the editor below. The function must return an array of integers where the value at each index $j$ denotes the answer for the $j$th query of type Total.
> `getTheGroups` has the following parameter(s):
>
> ```
> n: the number of students, integer
> queryType [queryType[1],...queryTpe[q]]: an array of query type strings
> student1 [student1[1],...student1[q]]: an array of student integer ID's
> student2 [student2[1],...student2[q]]: an array of student integer ID's
> ```
>
> Constraints
>
> ```
> 1 <= n <= 10 pow 5
> 1 <= q <= 10 pow 5
> 1 <= students1[i] <= n
> 1 <= students2[i] <= n
> queryType[i] is a member of {Friend, Total}
> ```
>
> Input Format.
> Input from stdin will be processed as follows and passed to the function.
>
> ```
> The first line contains an integer n, the number of students.
> The next line contains an integer q, the number of queries.
> Each of the next q lines contains a string queryType[i] where 1 <= i <= q.
> The next line contains an integer q, the number of students.
> Each of the next q lines contains a string students1[i] where 1 <= i <= q.
> The next line contains an integer q, the number of students.
> Each of the next q lines contains a string students2[i] where 1 <= i <= q.
> ```
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
>   3            - the number of students
>   2            - the number of queries
>   Friend       - queryType[1]
>   Total        - queryType[2]
>   2            - the number of queries
>   1            - student1[1]
>   2            - student1[2]
>   2            - then number of queries
>   2            - student2[1] 
>   3            - student2[2]
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
>  3
> ```

What I got from the problem was to take the sum of the size of all groups of friends?  So if student1, student2 are friends and student2, student3 are friends, then the sum would be 4?
I apologize for the rookie question. I genuinely couldn't make sense of the description.

Comment: Voting to close this question as too narrow (unlikely that anyone else in the future will find it useful).

Comment: Please credit the source of all copied material.

Comment: The question is very long.

Answer (score 0):

Read this sentence from the description carefully:

> If the query type is Friends the two students become friends. If the query type is Total, you must report the sum of the sizes of the groups of friends for the two students.

So your program must maintain a state between queries. The queries are read off sequentially by taking all of the first indices of the 3 arrays for the first query, then all the second indices of the 3 arrays for the second query, etc. The Friends query modifies the state, while the Total query accesses the state and returns "size of group containing student 1 + size of group containing student 2".

Comment: I still don't get it.  So if I have 2 groups of friends, wouldn't my output be 4?

Comment: @oo92 No, the output would be the sum of the sizes of the two groups containing the two students specified in the query. Each student is only in one group at a time, but two groups merge whenever a student from one becomes friends with a student from the other.

Comment: @oo92 In particular, if you have N students and run no Friends queries before running a Total query, the output of the Total query is necessarily 2 regardless of N and regardless of which two students are specified as the arguments to the Total query.

Comment: @oo92 Is this question for a class? If so, I would suggest you ask the instructor or TA for clarification if you are still unclear.

Comment: Its from a programming challenge.  I have 2 groups of friends with 2 friends in each group.  The sum of the sizes of the group makes 4, no?

Comment: @oo92 If the current state of the program when a Total query is evaluated is that there are 2 groups with 2 students in each group, then yes, the Total query would return 4 (regardless of which two students are the arguments to the Total query). But that wasn't what you wrote. You wrote "if I have 2 groups of friends, wouldn't my output be 4?" That is not enough information by itself.